# What is $\Gamma(a)$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm reading Van Lint's *Course in Combinatorics*:

> [image]

He mentions $\Gamma(a)$ in this text but I'm not really sure of what it means and I'm also afraid of assume something wrong, at first thought I assumed that it would be some vertice in $G$ and hence $\Gamma(A)$ would be all the vertices of a subset. I've skimmed the previous chapters of the book and found no mention to $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\Gamma(a)$ is the set of vertices adjacent to $a$. In the bipartite graph $G$ whose vertices are bipartitioned into the sets $X$ and $Y$, $\Gamma(x)\subseteq Y$ for each $x\in X$, and $\Gamma(y)\subseteq X$ for each $y\in Y$.

Comment: This notation is defined in the paragraph at the top of p. 4.

Comment: Thanks, @bof; I was too lazy to go out to the other room to find the book and check.